# OnBackInvokedCallback is not enabled for the application in Set 'android:enableOnBackInvokedCallback="true"' in the application manifest as warning

Tags: android-gesture, android-13, gesture-navigation

I'm running my Android Application `Android-13, in the Logcat I'm seeing this warning, How to resolve this?

```
OnBackInvokedCallback is not enabled for the application.
Set 'android:enableOnBackInvokedCallback="true"' in the application manifest.
```

Answer (score 54, accepted):

This is because of the Android Gesture Navigation, [reference link here](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/activity)

To help make predictive back gesture helpful and consistent for users, we're moving to an ahead-of-time model for back event handling by adding new APIs and deprecating existing APIs.

The new platform APIs and updates to AndroidX Activity 1.6+ are designed to make your transition from unsupported APIs (KeyEvent#KEYCODE_BACK and OnBackPressed) to the predictive back gesture as smooth as possible.

The new platform APIs include `OnBackInvokedCallback` and `OnBackInvokedDispatcher`, which AndroidX Activity 1.6+ supports through the existing `OnBackPressedCallback` and `OnBackPressedDispatcher` APIs.

You can start testing this feature in two to four steps, depending on your existing implementation.

> 1. Upgrade to AndroidX Activity 1.6.0-alpha05. By upgrading your dependency on AndroidX Activity, APIs that are already using the
>    `OnBackPressedDispatcher` APIs such as Fragments and the Navigation
>    Component will seamlessly work when you opt-in for the predictive back
>    gesture.

```
  // In your build.gradle file:
    dependencies {

  // Add this in addition to your other dependencies
  implementation "androidx.activity:activity:1.6.0-alpha05"
```

> 2. Opt-in for the predictive back gesture. Opt-in your app by setting the EnableOnBackInvokedCallback flag to true at the application level
>    in the AndroidManifest.xml.

```
<application

    ...

    android:enableOnBackInvokedCallback="true"

    ... >

...

</application>
```

> If your app doesn’t intercept the back event, you're done at this
> step. Note: Opt-in is optional in Android 13, and it will be ignored
> after this version.

```
 val onBackPressedCallback = object: OnBackPressedCallback(true) {

   override fun handleOnBackPressed() {

     // Your business logic to handle the back pressed event

   }

 }

 requireActivity().onBackPressedDispatcher

   .addCallback(onBackPressedCallback)
```

> 4. When your app is ready to stop intercepting the system Back event, disable the onBackPressedCallback callback.

```
onBackPressedCallback.isEnabled = webView.canGoBack()
```

> Note: Your app may require using the platform APIs
> (OnBackInvokedCallback and OnBackPressedDispatcher) to implement the
> predictive back gesture. Read our documentation for details.

Comment: You say "Your app may require using [both]... Read our documentation for details." Can you please point to that documentation? I haven't been able to find anything that talks about when one is required versus the other versus when both are. Thanks.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/predictive-back-gesture

Comment: The Android 13 version of this is really limiting compared to what came before. I notice that Android 14 is adding `OnBackAnimationCallback` to support the full cycle of start/progress/complete-or-cancel. Is there any reason `android:enableOnBackInvokedCallback` can't use a boolean resource keyed to API version? There's not a lot of documentation and I want to know if this is going to be supported rather than just guessing and hoping.

Comment: @j__m Yes, because if the resource is keyed to API version some may be forced to use it because the `Activity.onBackPressed` and `KeyEvent#KEYCODE_BACK` stop being called by the OS entirely.

In my case it is preventing Compose views from intercepting back presses entirely, and even skipping the `OnBackPressedCallback` registered to the (single) Activity.  At this point it is looking like the `OnBackPressedDispatcher` is null and now must also be set to the AbstractComposeView or `BackHandler` must be added to the Composable.

Answer (score -6):

Please verify if the android:enableOnBackInvokedCallback="true" attribute is included in the manifest file, and if it is present, remove it.

Comment: The error wants it to be true. Why are you removing it if it is there?