# Flutter Android app: OnBackInvokedCallback is not enabled for the application. Set enableOnBackInvokedCallback="true"

Tags: android, flutter

I am developing a flutter app for android (flutter version 3.3.9, compileSdkVersion = 33) and I see this in the console a lot:

```
    D/InputMethodManager(20966): showSoftInput() view=io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterView{55ec592 VFE...... .F....ID 0,0-1080,2337 #2 aid=1073741824} flags=0 reason=SHOW_SOFT_INPUT
    W/OnBackInvokedCallback(20966): OnBackInvokedCallback is not enabled for the application.
    W/OnBackInvokedCallback(20966): Set 'android:enableOnBackInvokedCallback="true"' in the application manifest.
    D/InsetsController(20966): show(ime(), fromIme=true)
    D/InputMethodManager(20966): showSoftInput() view=io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterView{55ec592 VFE...... .F...... 0,0-1080,2337 #2 aid=1073741824} flags=0 reason=SHOW_SOFT_INPUT
    D/InsetsController(20966): show(ime(), fromIme=true)
    D/InputMethodManager(20966): showSoftInput() view=io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterView{55ec592 VFE...... .F...... 0,0-1080,2337 #2 aid=1073741824} flags=0 reason=SHOW_SOFT_INPUT
    D/InsetsController(20966): show(ime(), fromIme=true)
```

Should I really set `enableOnBackInvokedCallback` to true? In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73782320/onbackinvokedcallback-is-not-enabled-for-the-application-in-set-androidenableo) SO question, the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73782321) explains why this happens.

But since I don't develop in native android but in flutter, is it the same for me?
Should I even care about this?

(Usually I let flutter manage all the native stuff and most of the time it's best not to change anything)

Comment: Seems to be answered here: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/132504

Answer (score 3):

I had set `android:enableOnBackInvokedCallback="true"` in `AndroidManifest.xml` in my Flutter app, but this seems to break the router back navigation (I tried with both `go_router` and `auto_route` and got the same issue).

Only the `AppBar` back button worked, but the device's own back button at the bottom of the screen just exited the app without stepping back through the pushed routes.

Comment: https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/android-predictive-back