# OnBackInvokedCallback is not enabled for the application in Set 'android:enableOnBackInvokedCallback="true"' in the application manifest warning

Tags: flutter

I am designing a Flutter forum app, and when I attempt to post a message, I receive the following error in the debug console on VSCode.

```
W/OnBackInvokedCallback(24004): OnBackInvokedCallback is not enabled for the application.
W/OnBackInvokedCallback(24004): Set 'android:enableOnBackInvokedCallback="true"' in the application manifest.
```

However in the AndroidManifest.xml file, I cannot find 'android:enableOnBackInvokedCallback'.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.kopimate">
   <application
        android:label="kopimate"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Lastly, the post does not show on the page, however on my project Firebase database it shows the post has been made.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add it by yourself.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.kopimate">
   <application
        android:label="kopimate"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:enableOnBackInvokedCallback="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
```

[Similar Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73782320/onbackinvokedcallback-is-not-enabled-for-the-application-in-set-androidenableo)