# GoRouter android back button causing nested navigation slow (sometimes unclickable) WindowOnBackDispatcher: sendCancelIfRunning: isInProgress=false

Tags: flutter, onbackpressed, nested-routes, gorouter

I am using Go Router for nested navigation on Flutter. The navigation works until I press the back button on the android phone then when I try to click nested navigation wrapped in bottom bar navigation it's slow to load or unclickable and I get this:

```
W/WindowOnBackDispatcher( 9978): sendCancelIfRunning: isInProgress=falsecallback=io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity$1@2a3415f
D/EGL_emulation( 9978): app_time_stats: avg=165.14ms min=5.89ms max=2133.05ms count=14
```

Also when click the android back button again it goes to the home screen.

Before I was getting this error:

```
OnBackInvokedCallback is not enabled for the application.
Set 'android:enableOnBackInvokedCallback="true"' in the application manifest.
```

So I set 'android:enableOnBackInvokedCallback="true"' in the main folder AndroidManifest.xml at application level. There are 2 other AndroidManifest.xml files in the debug and profile folder but I didn't set 'android:enableOnBackInvokedCallback="true"' in those and they also had no application level in the AndroidManifest.xml

After I set 'android:enableOnBackInvokedCallback="true"' in AndroidManifest the nested navigation continued to be unclickable after I hit the android phone backbutton but with error I mentioned before.

I have tried updating the version, upgrading AndroidX Activity and setting 'android:enableOnBackInvokedCallback="true"

```
 // In my build.gradle file:
    dependencies {

  // Added this in addition to my other dependencies
  implementation "androidx.activity:activity:1.6.0-alpha05"
```

basically I did step 1 and 2 of the answer by FGH then didn't know what to do about of what was mentioned in the rest of the steps I don't think it's relevant to my project because I don't have code for onBackPressedCallback(it might be in the background somewhere I don't know). [StackOverflow Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73782320/onbackinvokedcallback-is-not-enabled-for-the-application-in-set-androidenableo)

I don't think the steps in the stackoverflow mentioned above with work, maybe I have to overide
WindowOnBackDispatcher somehow I don't know. It looks like its because I am adding more screens to the nested navigation in the bottom navigation bar

Here is my Go Router Navigation:

```
 // GoRouter configuration
  static final GoRouter router = GoRouter(
    initialLocation: initial,
    debugLogDiagnostics: true,
    navigatorKey: _rootNavigatorKey,
    routes: [
      GoRoute(
        path: '/',
        builder: (context, state) => WelcomeScreen(),
        routes: [
          GoRoute(
            path: 'login',
            builder: (context, state) => LoginScreen(),
            routes: [
              GoRoute(
                  path: 'register',
                  name: 'Register',
                  builder: (context, state) => RegisterScreen()),
              GoRoute(
                  path: 'forgotPassword',
                  name: 'forgotPassword',
                  builder: (context, state) => ForgotPasswordScreen(),
                  routes: [
                    GoRoute(
                        path: 'OTPVerification',
                        name: 'OTPVerification',
                        builder: (context, state) => OtpVerificationScreen(),
                        routes: [
                          GoRoute(
                            path: 'createNewPassword',
                            name: 'createNewPassword',
                            builder: (context, state) =>
                                CreateNewPasswordScreen(),
                            routes: [
                              GoRoute(
                                  path: 'passwordChanged',
                                  name: 'passwordChanged',
                                  builder: (context, state) =>
                                      PasswordChangedScreen()),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ]),
                  ]),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),

      /// MainWrapper
      StatefulShellRoute.indexedStack(
        builder: (context, state, navigationShell) {
          return CustomBottomBar(
            navigationShell: navigationShell,
          );
        },
        branches: <StatefulShellBranch>[
          /// Branch Home
          StatefulShellBranch(
            navigatorKey: _shellNavigatorHome,
            routes: <RouteBase>[
              GoRoute(
                path: "/home",
                name: "Home",
                builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) =>
                    HomePage(),
                routes: [
                  GoRoute(
                    path: 'routesAndGamesList',
                    name: 'routesAndGamesList',
                    pageBuilder: (context, state) => CustomTransitionPage<void>(
                      key: state.pageKey,
                      child: RoutesAndGameList(),
                      transitionsBuilder:
                          (context, animation, secondaryAnimation, child) =>
                              FadeTransition(opacity: animation, child: child),
                    ),
                  ),
                  GoRoute(
                    path: 'routesList',
                    name: 'routesList',
                    pageBuilder: (context, state) => CustomTransitionPage<void>(
                      key: state.pageKey,
                      child: RoutesList(),
                      transitionsBuilder:
                          (context, animation, secondaryAnimation, child) =>
                              FadeTransition(opacity: animation, child: child),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
          StatefulShellBranch(
            navigatorKey: _shellNavigatorInfo,
            routes: <RouteBase>[
              GoRoute(
                path: "/info",
                name: "Info",
                builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) =>
                    InfoPage(),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          StatefulShellBranch(
            navigatorKey: _shellNavigatorProfile,
            routes: <RouteBase>[
              GoRoute(
                path: "/profile",
                name: "Profile",
                builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) =>
                    ProfilePage(),
                routes: <RouteBase>[
                  GoRoute(
                    path: 'achievements',
                    name: 'Achievements',
                    pageBuilder: (context, state) => CustomTransitionPage<void>(
                      key: state.pageKey,
                      child: AchievementsScreen(),
                      transitionsBuilder:
                          (context, animation, secondaryAnimation, child) =>
                              FadeTransition(opacity: animation, child: child),
                    ),
                    routes: [
                      GoRoute(
                        path: 'trophy',
                        name: 'Trophy',
                        builder: (context, state) => TrophyScreen(),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
          StatefulShellBranch(
            navigatorKey: _shellNavigatorStories,
            routes: <RouteBase>[
              GoRoute(
                path: "/stories",
                name: "Stories",
                builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) =>
                    StoriesPage(),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ],
  );
```